# Order of events in xaml

Tags: .net, xaml

New to xaml. I've got a TextBox where both the text value and the changed event are bound in  the xaml. I need for the text's value binding mechanism to run before the changed event when a value is keyed. How do I enforce this?

```
<TextBox x:Class="WPF.AppControls.TextBoxAppControl"
         xmlns="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml/presentation"
         xmlns:x="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml"
         xmlns:mc="http://schemas.openxmlformats.org/markup-compatibility/2006" 
    IsEnabled="{Binding Enabled}"
    Visibility="{Binding Visibility}"
    Text="{Binding Text}" 
    GotFocus="TextBox_GotFocus"
    LostFocus="TextBox_LostFocus"
    TextChanged="TextBox_TextChanged"
    KeyDown="TextBox_KeyDown">

</TextBox>
```

Comment: post the relevant code and XAML.

Comment: which platform WPF,windows phone, winRT?

Comment: Why do you need such behavior? Maybe there's a better way to do what you're trying to do.

Comment: Intended to be used on any of the platforms you listed

Answer (score 0):

If you need to get Text updated when the text change instead of on focus lost, on WPF you can just replace your binding by `Text="{Binding Text,UpdateSourceTrigger=PropertyChanged}"` 
On other platform you will need to create an attached property, something like that should do it:

```
public class MyAttachedProperties
{
    public static readonly DependencyProperty MyTextProperty =
        DependencyProperty.RegisterAttached("MyText", typeof (string), typeof (MyAttachedProperties), new PropertyMetadata(default(string),TextChanged));

    private static void TextChanged(DependencyObject d, DependencyPropertyChangedEventArgs e)
    {

        TextBox tb = d as TextBox;

        tb.TextChanged -= tb_TextChanged;
        tb.TextChanged += tb_TextChanged;
        string newText = e.NewValue as String;
        if (tb.Text != newText)
        {
            tb.Text = newText;
        }
    }

    static void tb_TextChanged(object sender, TextChangedEventArgs e)
    {
        TextBox tb = sender as TextBox;
        SetMyText(tb, tb.Text);

    }

    public static void SetMyText(UIElement element, string value)
    {
        element.SetValue(MyTextProperty, value);
    }

    public static string GetMyText(UIElement element)
    {
        return (string) element.GetValue(MyTextProperty);
    }
}
```

That you can use like this: `local:MyAttachedProperties.MyText="{Binding Text}"` (and remove the normal Text binding)

Answer (score 0):

One of possible way:

Bind custom dependency property(http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms753358.aspx) to TextBox.Text and specify PropertyChangedCallback (http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.windows.propertychangedcallback.aspx) for it.